# Did COBOL have 250 billion lines of code and 1 million programmers, as late as 2009?

Tags: computers, technology, software

In 2009 COBOL turned 50 years old. It got some publicity with claims, which I find rather hard to believe:

["Cobol hits 50 and keeps counting" article in the Guardian](http://www.guardian.co.uk/technology/2009/apr/09/cobol-internet-programming).

> According to David Stephenson, the UK
> manager for the software provider
> Micro Focus, "some 70% to 80% of UK
> plc business transactions are still
> based on Cobol".
>
> [...]
>
> A lot of this maintenance and
> development takes place on IBM
> products. The company's software group
> director of product delivery and
> strategy, Charles Chu, says that he
> doesn't think "legacy" is pejorative.
> "Business constantly evolves," he
> adds, "but **there are 250bn lines of
> Cobol code working well worldwide.** Why
> would companies replace systems that
> are working well?"

Often quoted [forum/blog post "50 years on, Cobol still as influential"](http://www.desilashkary.com/forum/showthread.php?t=956).

> The statistics on Cobol attest to its
> huge influence on the business world:
> There are over **220 billion lines of
> Cobol in existence, a figure which
> equates to about 80 per cent of the
> world’s actively used code. There over
> a million Cobol programmers in the
> world.** There are 200 times as many
> Cobol transactions that take place
> each day than Google searches.

Jeff Atwood took a stab at it in his blog post ["COBOL: Everywhere and Nowhere"](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/08/cobol-everywhere-and-nowhere.html). Problem is, that it's only anecdotal evidence.

Recently [subject surfaced on Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/45754/over-a-million-cobol-programmers-in-the-world), but so far it's also only anecdotal evidence.

Is there any hard data on:

- total number of lines of all code in use?
- total number of lines of COBOL code in use?
- total number of all programmers?
- total number of COBOL programmers?

Comment: Here are two links that might be helpful: [EE Times](http://www.eetimes.com/discussion/break-point/4026908/A-Trillion-Lines-of-Code-),  [Dr.Dobbs](http://drdobbs.com/web-development/210602491?pgno=2)

Comment: Remember, 1 million lines of COBOL can be rewritten in about 10 lines of C.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### Nobody knows.

**None of the sources for total LOC provide any means or methods.**

*Sources for hard numbers after 2008 were a little hard to come by, my apologies.*

**Total number of lines of all code in use?**

- One trillion (2001).<sup>[19]</sup>

  - C/C++: 180 billion, Assembler: 140-220 billion, Other: 280 billion.

**Total number of lines of COBOL code in use?**

- 200 billion (2008).<sup>[10]</sup>
- 180 billion (2006).<sup>[12]</sup>
- 200 billion (2005).<sup>[14]</sup>
- 225 billion (2001).<sup>[19]</sup>
- 100 billion (2000).<sup>[21]</sup>

**Total number of all programmers?**

- 14.6 million (2009).<sup>[8]</sup>

**Total number of COBOL programmers?**

- 1.5 - 2 million (2008).<sup>[19]</sup>
- ~2 million (2000).<sup>[20]</sup>

If we consider the fact that there are at least 2000 banks in the U.S. alone and that the sources below give numbers between 100 thousand LOC and 343 million LOC for financial systems; Well it adds up fast.

Once you throw in civil and military systems...it's at least one billion.

---

### Sources

### 2012

> **1.** Case study In this work we analyze a Cobol software portfolio of a
>   **large organization operating in the financial sector**. The Cobol
>   sources are a mixture of code written manually and generated with
>   Computer-Aided Software Engineering (CASE) tools, such as TELON,
>   COOL:Gen, CANAM, and others.
>
> The portfolio is decades-old and large in many dimensions; for
>   example, in terms of lines of code, number of systems, or number of
>   modules. To give an idea, the **portfolio contains more than 18.2
>   million physical lines of code (LOC)** partitioned over 47 information
>   systems.

- Kwiatkowski, L. M., & Verhoef, C. (2012). [Recovering management information from source code.](http://www.cs.vu.nl/~x/rmsc/rmsc.pdf) Science of Computer Programming.

---

> **2.** David Brown is worried. As managing director of the IT transformation
>   group at Bank of New York Mellon, he is responsible for the health and
>   welfare of **112,500 Cobol programs, 343 million lines of code, that run
>   core banking and other operations**. But many of the people who built
>   that code base, some of which goes back to the early days of Cobol in
>   the 1960s, will be retiring over the next several years.
>
> That's the situation faced by Jim Gwinn, chief information officer for
>   the USDA's Farm Service Agency. "**We have millions of lines of Cobol**
>   and there's a long history of it being rewritten," he says. "It has
>   become increasingly difficult to change the code because of the
>   complexity and the attrition of the knowledge base that wrote it."

- Mitchell, R.L. (March 15, 2012) [Cobol on the mainframe: Does it have a future?](http://features.techworld.com/applications/3344704/cobol-on-mainframe-does-it-have-future/) ComputerWorld.

---

### 2011

> **3.** We prototyped and applied the proposed strategy on a set of programs
>   from our clients execution environment. These programs were of varying
>   lengths **from a few thousand lines of code to around 80 KLOC**.

- Jiresal, R., Contractor, A., & Naik, R. (2011, September). [Precise detection of un-initialized variables in large, real-life COBOL programs in presence of unrealizable paths.](http://www.tcs-trddc.com/trddc_website/pdf/SWR/jiresal_pdouivilrlcpipourp_2011.pdf) In Software Maintenance (ICSM), 2011 27th IEEE International Conference on (pp. 448-456). IEEE.

---

> **4.** The subject software system of this case study is an excerpt of a
>   confidential **100k LOC COBOL system from the banking industry**. It
>   consists of approximately 1,100 sections in 150 programs and copybooks
>   (include files).

- Beck, M., Trumper, J., & Dollner, J. (2011, September). [A visual analysis and design tool for planning software reengineerings.](http://www.hpi.uni-potsdam.de/fileadmin/hpi/FG_Doellner/publications/2011/BTD2011/beck_vissoft2011_preprint.pdf) In Visualizing Software for Understanding and Analysis (VISSOFT), 2011 6th IEEE International Workshop on (pp. 1-8). IEEE.

---

### 2010

> **5.** VisualAge PACBASE is an application generator. **Billions of lines of
>   COBOL exist all over the world, which have been produced with this
>   environment.** For historical reasons, such applications require
>   specific execution contexts, namely old terminals (non graphical
>   window-based screens), mainframes and CICS (Customer Information
>   Control System).
>
> The business scope of SCAFRUITS is broad: **order management, shipping,
>
>   supplier and product qualification and referencing, timely price management, 
>   product activation/inhibition**…
>
> Concerning its technical facets, the **size of the application is
>   estimated to be equal to 3M of LoC**, 600 programs, 400 screens, 200
>   batch programs, 300 potential users, 48,000 product references with
>   only 2,000 active references at a time. **There are 350,000 transactions
>   per day and 100,000 created order lines per day**.

- Barbier, F., Eveillard, S., Youbi, K., & Cariou, E. (2010). [Model-driven reverse engineering of COBOL-based applications.](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.158.9504&rep=rep1&type=pdf#page=42) Information Systems Transformation. Architecture Driven Modernization Case Studies, Morgan Kauffman, Burlington, MA, 283-299.

---

> **6.** The system under investigation in this paper is a **large-sized (> 1
>   MLOC) industrial application** that supports **the core activities (e.g.,
>   insurances and mortgages) of a major, Belgian bank**. Despite that work
>   on the **system started as recent as 2005**, the bank opted to develop the
>   back-end of this **new system in COBOL** in order to ease integration with
>   existing infrastructure.

- Kellens, A., Noguera, C., D'Hondt, T., Jorissen, L., & Van Passel, B. (2010, September). [Verifying the design of an outsourced COBOL system with IntensiVE.](ftp://prog.vub.ac.be/tech_report/2010/vub-tr-soft-10-13.pdf) In Software Maintenance (ICSM), 2010 IEEE International Conference on (pp. 1-8). IEEE.

---

> **7.** Project: The National Endowment for the Arts (NEA). [M]odernization of
>   the NEA’s business systems (Financial Management – Grants Management -
>   Automated Panel Bank)
>
> Fully **modernized the 656,000 LOC of Wang-COBOL** & RMS flat files to C++
>   & SQL Server environment & 3,270 screens into a MS Windows
>   environment.
>
> Project: Northrop Grumman. [T]ransformation demonstration and
>   subsequent modernization of the Increments 1 & 3 of the Air Force’s
>   REMIS system.
>
> Fully **modernized over 400,000 LOC of Tandem COBOL** to both C++ & Java
>   code.

- Newcomb, P. (2010) [How Architecture-Driven Modernization Is Changing the Game in Information System Modernization.](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a558512.pdf) The Software Revolution, Inc.

---

### 2009

> **8.** For 2009, Evans Data originally estimated that there would be
>   approximately 15.2 million developers worldwide. However, it has
>   reduced that estimated by about 600,000 in the current report.
>
> In North America, Evans Data projected in a previous report that the
>   developer population would grow to 3.85 million in North America
>   during 2009. In the current report, it changed that figure to 3.72
>   million based on current economic conditions. Evans did not disclose
>   data on other regions.

- Feinman, J. (June 12, 2009) [Software developers becoming scarce.](http://www.sdtimes.com/content/article.aspx?ArticleID=33548&page=1) SD Times.

---

> **9.** The Social Security Administration is wrapping essential Cobol
>   applications in Extensible Markup Language envelopes and publishing
>   them as service-oriented architecture services. It will **retain about
>   20 percent of the 36 million lines of Cobol** code it uses, Hill said.

- Robinson, B. (July 9, 2009) [Cobol remains old standby at agencies despite showing its age.](http://fcw.com/articles/2009/07/13/tech-cobol-turns-50.aspx) ComputerWorld.

---

### 2008

> **10.** Recent statistics quoted to Datamonitor by IBM reveal the massive scale of intellectual property accumulated:
>
> • Around 200 billion lines of COBOL code are in live operation.
>   • 75% of the world’s business data, and 90% of financial transactions, are
>   processed in COBOL.
>   • There are 1.5 – 2 million developers, globally, working with COBOL code.
>   • Around 5 billion lines of new COBOL code are added to live systems every year.

- Datamonitor, (November 2008) [COBOL – continuing to drive value in the 21st Century.](http://www.microfocus.com/000/COBOL_continuing_to_drive_value_in_the_21st_Century_tcm21-23652.pdf)

---

### 2007

> **11. Legacy COBOL systems usually contain millions of lines of code (LOC)**
>   spread over thousands of modules, developed by tens of people over
>   many years, are often poorly documented and, to a large extent,
>   knowledge about them is lost.
>
> We used SQuAVisiT to study a large COBOL legacy system of a **large
>   insurance fund: 3 thousand modules, 1.7 million LOCs**.

- Roubtsov, S., Telea, A., & Holten, D. (2007, September). [SQuAVisiT: a software quality assessment and visualisation toolset.](http://www.cs.rug.nl/~alext/PAPERS/SCAM07/paper.pdf) In Source Code Analysis and Manipulation, 2007. SCAM 2007. Seventh IEEE International Working Conference on (pp. 155-156). IEEE.

---

### 2006

> **12.** Gartner has estimated that there are 180 billion lines of Cobol code
>   in use around the world.

- Washington, L. (November 13, 2006) [Cobol: The New Latin. This 'dead language' must be embraced and taught.](http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9004821/Cobol_The_New_Latin) ComputerWorld.

---

### 2005

> **13.** The customer of the authors is a **mid-size German company providing
>   financial services**. These services are based upon two large
>   application  systems, which share the same HP UNIX platform, but
>   belong to completely different worlds of software technology.
>
> •  The total COBOL system consists of 1398 batch programs, 485 on-line
>   programs and 7621 copy modules.
>   •  The total number of lines (LOC) is
>   nearly 2 million, **after deducting the comments (~ 25%) the actual code
>   reaches approximately 1.5 million lines**.
>   •  The system is maintained
>   by a staff of 8.
>
> Calculating with only 8 % of the net LOC **means 120,000 code lines per
>   year added, changed or deleted by eight programmers**. Assuming 80MM
>   effort a year the maintenance productivity is 1500 code lines per
>   person month.

- Nyáry, E., Pap, G., Herczegh, M., & Kolonits, Z. (2005) [Supporting the Maintenance of legacy COBOL Applications with Tools for Repository Management and Viewing.](http://www.inf.u-szeged.hu/icsm2005/postevent/ICSM2005-Industrial_proceedings.pdf#page=5) Message from the Industry Co-Chairs, 5.

---

> **14.** For example, **Cobol remains the most widely deployed programming
>   language in big business, accounting for 75% of all computer
>   transactions** and it is not going to go away. Cobol is pervasive in the
>   financial sector (**accounting for 90% of all financial transactions**),
>   in defense, as well as within established manufacturing and insurance
>   sectors. **We estimate that there are over 200 billion lines of Cobol in
>   production today**, and this number **continues to grow by between three
>   and five percent a year**.

- Barnett, G. (2005). [The future of the mainframe.](http://ovum.com/section/home/) Ovum, October.

---

> **15.** While the paper is shaped by a very tractable example project (just
>   90,000 LOC), we have applied the same methodology in other projects.
>   For instance, the methodology for analyzing impact, and for estimating
>   effort and costs was also used to provide a customer with precise
>   information **on a project where a 50 million LOC** software portfolio had
>   to be investigated for the architectural modification of existing bank
>   account numbers to ten digits.

- Klusener, A. S., Lämmel, R., & Verhoef, C. (2005). [Architectural modifications to deployed software.](http://homepages.cwi.nl/~ralf/am/paper.pdf) Science of Computer Programming, 54(2), 143-211.

---

### 2004

> **16.** With **an estimated 60% to 80% of all business applications still
>   written in COBOL**, it was no surprise to find exactly this in the code
>   base of the companies involved in ARRIBA. COBOL therefore quickly
>   gained much of our focus.
>
> The code is badly structured and poorly documented. **The amount of code
>   is huge (millions of LOC)** and has been adapted many times for several
>   reasons (switching platforms, year 2000 conversions, transition to the
>   Euro currency,…). So keeping the documentation synchronized with those
>   evolutionary changes didn't always happen.

- Michiels, I., D’Hondt, T., De Schutter, K., & Hoffman, G. (2004, March). [Using dynamic aspects to distill business rules from legacy code.](http://www2.riacs.edu/research/technical_reports/docs/TR_04.01.pdf#page=103) In Dynamic Aspects Workshop (DAW04) (p. 1).

---

> **17.** During the last three decades, a considerable amount of software was
>   developed using procedural languages. For example, **Coyle estimates the
>   size of systems written in Cobol to be more than 100 billion LOC.**

- Wu, L., Sahraoui, H., & Valtchev, P. (2004, November). [Automatic detecting code cooperation.](https://ritdml.rit.edu/bitstream/handle/1850/9859/LWuConfProc11-2004.pdf?sequence=1) In Software Engineering Conference, 2004. 11th Asia-Pacific (pp. 204-211). IEEE.

---

> **18.** Two case studies were carried out with our transformations on
>   real-life industrial Cobol systems.
>   The source code in the first case study **was IBM Cobol and came from
>   the same banking company** as the code of the source base. There was one
>   large **system of 2.6 million LOC in almost 1000 programs**. The program
>   sizes ranged from about 40 to 13000 LOC. The number of statements per
>   program ranged from two to 4000 statements. In the whole system, there
>   were about 400000 statements.
>
> In the second case study several systems that were **written in Micro
>   Focus Cobol were transformed**. Similar to the first case study, the
>   **total size was 2.6 million LOC, but this was a coincidence. The source
>   code consisted of almost 3000 programs** and the sizes of the individual
>   programs ranged from 25 to 8000 LOC. The number of statements per
>   program ranged from 10 to almost 3400. In total, **there were over 1.2
>   million statements**. This significant higher number of statements
>   compared with the first case study was because in the first case study
>   a great deal of code was used for data declarations.

- Veerman, N. (2004). [Revitalizing modifiability of legacy assets.](http://www.math.vu.nl/~nveerman/research/revitalizing/revitalizing.pdf) Journal of Software Maintenance and Evolution: Research and Practice, 16(4-5), 219-254.

---

### 2001

> **19.** First, there are about 300 Cobol dialects, and each compiler product has a few versions—with many patch levels. Also, Cobol often
>   contains embedded languages such as DMS, DML, CICS, and SQL. So there
>   is no such thing as "the Cobol language." It is a polyglot, a
>   confusing mixture of dialects and embedded languages—a 500-Language
>   Problem of its own. Second, according to Jones, **the world's installed
>   software is distributed by language as follows:**
>   •  **Cobol: 30 percent (225 billion LOC)**
>   •  C/C++: 20 percent (180 billion LOC)
>   •  Assembler: 10 percent (140 to 220 billion LOC)
>   •  less common languages: 40 percent (280 billion LOC)
>
> Because **there are about a trillion lines of installed software
>   written in myriad languages**, its solution is a step forward in
>   managing those assets.

- Lammel, R., & Verhoef, C. (2001). [Cracking the 500-language problem](http://www.cs.vu.nl/grammarware/500/500.pdf). Software, IEEE, 18(6), 78-88.

---

### 2000

> **20.** There are about two million COBOL programmers in the world - more than
>   twice the number of JAVA programmers.

- Kizior, R. J., Carr, D., & Halpern, P. (2000) [Does COBOL Have a Future?.](http://proc.isecon.org/2000/126/ISECON.2000.Kizior.pdf)

---

> **21. Estimated at over 100 billion lines of code, most of it Cobol**, it
>   drives the world's infrastructure. The end result is a new
>   appreciation of legacy and a search for ways to capitalize on its
>   potential.

- Coyle, F. P. (2000). [Legacy integration-changing perspectives.](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=841604) IEEE Software, 17(2), 37-41.

---

### 1996

> **22.** However, we have just (January 1996) embarked on a large project
>   dealing with this subject, **in collaboration with several industrial
>   partners including the Dutch ABN-AMRO bank**, and we feel that this
>   application is too interesting to leave undiscussed in a paper on
>   industrial applications of ASF+SDF. **The problem at hand involves the
>   analysis, cleaning-up and reconstruction of a large suite (25,000
>   programs, 30M LOC) of mainframe-based COBOL applications**. The two main
>   problems currently studied are conversions between COBOL dialects and
>   identification and correction of software errors related to the "year
>   2000".

- van den Brand, M., van Deursen, A., Klint, P., Klusener, A. S., & van der Meulen, E. (1996) [Industrial applications of ASF+SDF](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.76.5906&rep=rep1&type=pdf) CS-R9622.

Comment: Many of these references simply speak to the existence of individual large codebases or beg the question ("Gartner has estimated that there are 180 billion lines of Cobol code in use"). Can you edit to point to some kind of primary source?

Comment: @LarryOBrien Sure. Are you looking for means and methods or would a consensus do?

Comment: I'd certainly prefer something with a published methodology. Gartner, to name a major offender, has been quite unreliable over the years but is never called to task. They were one of the major promoters of the extraordinarily poorly-sourced and vastly over-hyped Y2K impact (Gartner predicted $300-$600B in direct costs, "at least 1" theft in excess of $1B, and that 50% of organizations would suffer at least 1 mission-critical failure due to Y2K).